# Howto extend the buffer class in node.js

Tags: node.js, buffer

I want to extend the Buffer class in node.js (>= v4) but since there is no constructor this seems to be impossible.

```
class ExtendedBuffer extends Buffer {
    additionalMethod () {
        // do something
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only static initializer I would say that it is not possible.